# Error on start of kgraphviewer -- /snap/kgraphviewer/2/kf5-launch: line 209: /snap/kgraphviewer/2/kf5-locale-gen: No such file or directory

Tags: kde-apps

I installed kgraphviewer following the steps [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/kgraphviewer-dev_2.1.90-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb.html), namely `sudo apt-get install kgraphviewer-dev` but when I start kgraphviewer I get the error message

```
/snap/kgraphviewer/2/kf5-launch: line 209: /snap/kgraphviewer/2/kf5-locale-gen: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to fix the problem? Ubuntu version 18.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to install the application as normal deb-package:

```
sudo apt install kgraphviewer
```

and remove broken snapped one with:

```
snap remove kgraphviewer
```

Also please note that all current Ubuntu releases have this package versioned as [2.1.90](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kgraphviewer). You may be interested to contact Snap `kgraphviewer` package developers (KDE) and [inform them](https://snapcraft.io/kgraphviewer) about error in their package.

Comment: kgraphviewer no longer exists in 19.10 :(  And the snap gives the same error ...